# Filter data in long format using dropdown menu with plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to filter data, which is in a long format, using dropdown menu in plotly. However, I might be misunderstanding something as I am not getting the proper results. I want to combine this with faceting, but that is not shown in the code below. I tried two ways that did not work (they fail in different ways) and I don't understand what is wrong with them.

Specifically, what you'll notice is as you change the dropdown menu selection the following information is incorrect: color of the data points, hover data information, legend and displayed data. (This will depend on whether attempt 1 or attempt 2 code is used)

Here is the code I am using (without faceting) on Iris dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

dropdown_menu = [
    {
        'label': 'All Categories',
        'method': 'update',
        'args': [{
                  'visible': True
               },
               
     {'title': 'All Categories'}]}
]
 
 
dropdown_menu.extend(
    [{'label': cat,
      'method': 'update',
      'args': [{
       ### Attempt 1
                  'visible': df['species'] == cat,

       ### Attempt 2
                  #'y': [df[df['species'] == cat]['petal_length']],
                  #'x': [df[df['species'] == cat]['petal_width']],
               },
               
     {'title': cat}]} for cat in df['species'].unique()]
)
 
fig = px.line(
    df,
    x='petal_width', 
    y='petal_length', 
    color='species', 
    line_group='species', 
    markers = True)#, facet_col='other categorical feature')
 
fig.update_layout(
    {'updatemenus': [
        {
            'type': 'dropdown',
            'buttons': dropdown_menu,
            'direction': 'down',
            'showactive': True,
            'active': 0,
            'x': 0.15,
            'xanchor': 'left',
            'y': 1.15,
            'yanchor': 'top'
        }
   ]}
)
```

Side question: what is the purpose of the square brackets in my second attempt? I am getting different results without them.

Comment: It is easier to use the display attribute to control visibility, as in this example from the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/#update-dropdown).

Comment: There is no `display` attribute referenced in the link.

Comment: The display attribute refers to `visible=True` . `for cat in data['species'].unique():
    df = data.query('species == @cat')
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df['petal_width'],
        y=df['petal_length'],
        name=cat,
        mode='lines',
        visible=True
    ))`

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the issue using traces and using plotly graphics objects instead of plotly express. I'm not sure if there is a way to do it without using traces. This does not accommodate the use of faceting as requested in the question.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Load dataset
df = px.data.iris()

# Initialize figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add Traces
for cat in df['species'].unique():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=list(df[df['species'] == cat]['petal_width']),
                   y=list(df[df['species'] == cat]['petal_length']),
                   # color=[df[df['species'] == cat]['species']],
                   # line_group=[df[df['species'] == cat]['species']],
                   visible=True,
                   name=cat,
                   mode='markers'
                  )
    )

dropdown_menu = [
    {
        'label': 'All Categories',
        'method': 'update',
        'args': [{
                  'visible': [True for cat_opt in df['species'].unique()],
               },
               
     {'title': 'All Categories'}]}
]
 
 
dropdown_menu.extend(
    [{'label': cat,
      'method': 'update',
      'args': [{
                  'visible': [cat_opt == cat for cat_opt in df['species'].unique()]
               },
               
     {'title': cat}]} for cat in df['species'].unique()]
)

fig.update_layout(
    {'updatemenus': [
        {
            'type': 'dropdown',
            'buttons': dropdown_menu,
            'direction': 'down',
            'showactive': True,
            'active': 0,
            'x': 0.15,
            'xanchor': 'left',
            'y': 1.2,
            'yanchor': 'top'
        }
   ]}
)

fig.show()
```

#### Alternative approach:

If you are okay with using `ipywidget`. The following would work:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact
 
# Create a DataFrame for Iris data
df = px.data.iris()
 
# Define a function to update the graph based on the selected species
def update_graph(selected_species):
    filtered_df = df[df['species'] == selected_species]
    fig = px.scatter(filtered_df, x='petal_width', y='petal_length', color='species')
    fig.show()
 
# Create a dropdown widget with unique species values
species_dropdown = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=df['species'].unique(),
    description='Select Species:'
)
 
# Use the interact function to update the graph when the dropdown value changes
interact(update_graph, selected_species=species_dropdown)
```